# If window.location ends with html execute javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, window.location

Execute javascript if current location contains html in in. I have tried the below but it doesn't work

```
var winloc = window.location; //for e.g http://mysite.com/home.html
var ishtml = winloc.match(/html/$);
var dothtml = "html";
if(dothtml==ishtml){
//execute javascript here
}
```

Comment: Use `location.pathname`. You surely don't want to match: `index.php?type=.html` (query string) or `foo#hi.html` (hash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isHTML = "html" === window.location.pathname.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
if ( isHTML ) {
    //execute javascript here
}
```

See Amaan answer using regexp:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619635/887539

Comment: +1. I like your method, but in this case, I think using a Regular Expression will be faster.

Comment: This breaks if the path-name happens to not have a dot.

Comment: Just thought I'd make a JSPerf test. Regular Expressions were faster for me. http://jsperf.com/pop-vs-regexp

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Disn't break, just returns the whole pathname as first element in the array. Only way it will break is if the `pathname == "html"`

Answer (score 1):

```
var winloc = window.location.pathname; //for e.g http://mysite.com/home.html
var ishtml = /html$/i.test(winloc); //Remove the i if you want to match only html and not HTML
if(ishtml === true){
    //Your JS
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V83hA/1/)

Comment: Maybe you want to add case-insensitive `/html$/i.test(winloc)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var winloc = window.location; //for e.g http://mysite.com/home.html
var ishtml = winloc.match(/html$/i);
var dothtml = "html";
if(dothtml==ishtml){
//execute javascript here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
if ( window.location.pathname.match( /html$/ ) ) {
    // do it
}
```

You don't have to declare local variables if the value are only needed once...

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /.*(\.html)$/i;
var winloc = window.location.href; //for e.g http://mysite.com/home.html
var ishtml = winloc.match(re)[1];
var dothtml = ".html";
if(dothtml==ishtml){
//execute javascript here
 alert("yes")
}
```