# append <script> to all pages but these

Tags: jquery, appendto

Thank you very much in advance for any help on this one.

I am appending a tracking script to a few pages - code below.  Now we need to append the script to all pages except one. I am lost on how to do this.

How can you append a script to all pages but /index3.html?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var identifier = window.location.pathname;
    switch(identifier)
    {
        case: 'index.html';
            $('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cti.w55c.net/ct/ct-f20dc88483814e189d5436461ea953ae.js"></' + 'script>').appendTo(document.body);
        break;

        case: 'About.aspx';
            $('<script>Tracking Pixel XYZ</' + 'script>').appendTo(document.body);
            break;
    }

});
```

Again thank you.

Comment: What does it matter if it's included on `index3.html`?  That is not a case of the switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**JQUERY**

```
var identifier = window.location.pathname;
if (identifier.indexOf("index3.html")  >= 0) {
  var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
  var url = 'http://cti.w55c.net/ct/ct-f20dc88483814e189d5436461ea953ae.js';
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;
  $("#someElement").append( script );
}
```

This will verify if the current location is `index3.html`, if not, create the `script` tag and append it to your element.

The comparison by greater <sup>></sup> and equal <sup>=</sup> makes sure that if value is found at position 0, it will match!

---

Javascript [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

---

### EDITED

**To check for two files...**

```
if ( (identifier.indexOf("index3.html") >= 0)
  || (identifier.indexOf("index4.html") >= 0)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you Zuul for great response. In the indexOf ("index3.html") how can I list two different pages? ("index3.html", "index4.html")?

Comment: Check the edit! But if you need to check many many files to exclude, an array would be preferable!

Answer (score 0):

```
var winloc = window.location.pathname;
var isindex3 = /index3$/i.test(winloc);
if(ishtml === true){
//add script to pages that are index3.html
}else{
//if you want add script to pages that are not index3.html
}
```

[If window.location ends with html execute javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619552/if-window-location-ends-with-html-execute-javascript/8619635#8619635)